# tqdm: when using multiple progress bars, do not remove finished bars

Tags: python, progress-bar, tqdm

When using multiple tqdm progress bars together, and once some of them are finished, they will NOT keep their bars, instead, the whole bar part will disappear:

[image]

I want them to keep their length (i.e. a solid full-length bar). How can I do that?

Here is a demo script

```py
from tqdm import tqdm
import time
import concurrent.futures

bars = []
for i in range(3):
    bars.append(tqdm(total=1024, unit="B", unit_scale=True, leave=None, unit_divisor=1024, ncols=100, position=i))

def upload_chunk(chunk_no):
    bar = bars[chunk_no % 3]

    if chunk_no == 0:
        size = 1024*1024*10
    else:
        size = 1024*1024*5
    if bar:
        bar.desc = f'chunk {chunk_no + 1}/{3}'
        bar.reset(total=size)
    def gen():
        offset = 0
        while True:
            if offset < size:
                update_chunk = 1024*200
                time.sleep(0.1)
                yield 'something'
                offset += update_chunk
                if bar:
                    bar.update(update_chunk)
            else:
                break
    result = list(gen())
    return result

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as ex:
    for i in range(0, 3):
        ex.submit(upload_chunk, i)

for bar in bars:
    bar.close()

print('Done!')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently, it's actually a mistake in the code.

When you try to update the bar with more than total, this will happen.

Simply change it to

```py
bar.update(min(update_chunk, size - offset))
offset += update_chunk
```

will fix the problem.

Another thing to note is that if you change too fast (like in this case), sometimes the bar doesn't upload the last tick and it's stuck at 98% instead of 100%. You can fix it by forcing bar.refresh() after each update().